# Live data over the internet

Tags: vb.net, winforms, web

I have a very simple visual basic winform application which is just a counter. How can I see this data live in a web page?

Here is my code:

```
Public Function GetTime(Time as Integer) As String
   Dim Hrs        As Integer  'number of hours   '
   Dim Min        As Integer  'number of Minutes '
   Dim Sec        As Integer  'number of Sec     '

   'Seconds'
   Sec = Time Mod 60

   'Minutes'
   Min = ((Time - Sec) / 60) Mod 60

   'Hours'
   Hrs = ((Time - (Sec + (Min * 60))) / 3600) Mod 60

   Return Format(Hrs, "00") & ":" & Format(Min, "00") & ":" & Format(Sec, "00")
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make a webpage and send it with an HTTP Request from Excel

Follow the steps on this site: https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/

Here is an example of what the POST Request could look like to send the data you have above (I have not tested this but it looks right):

```
Public Sub sendRunTime(min as Integer, sec as Integer, hrs as Integer)
  Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP, myurl As String
  myurl = "http://url/15oxrjh1"
  xmlhttp.Open "POST", myurl, False
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  xmlhttp.Send "min="&min&"&sec="&sec&"&hrs="&hrs
End Sub
```

Another option which is not as live but still pretty darn fast would be to have VBA update an entry in a SQL database which the webpage can then read. If you are looking to send the applications runtime to the website this is not the best bet but if you update it every minute just to know that the app is still running from a remote location this could work.

Comment: thakn you so much for your respone. What about the http code?

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at this site and learning to do some of the coding if this is the type or thing you want to do. http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp